# How can I analyze heapdump fetched from spring boot admin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, visualvm, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have an Spring boot application that is running in production, but we encountered some memory problems. I've got heapdump with the help of Spring Boot Admin, then I try to open this file with Eclipse memory analyzer but it fails and logs this error (I tried visualvm too):
`Detected compressed references, because with uncompressed 64-bit references the array at 0x60397eca8 would overlap the array at 0x60397ec90`
The heapdump size that Spring boot Admin provides never reach 50 MB but when I run the same application on my local the file size is 180 MB and it works perfectly with Analyzer.

On my local I obtain heapdump with actuator and as I undestand Spring boot Admin uses the same endpoints too.
Does anyone have any knowledge how can I analyze this file or if I needed to decompress this file?